# there was a network error....Upgrading to Cordova 2.8.0 from 2.7.0 in android

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

trying to upgrade to Cordova 2.8.0 from 2.7.0 and using JQuery 1.7.2 and JQuery-Mobile 1.1.1  following this link:[upgrading link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_upgrading_android_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Cordova%20Android)

but unfortunately failed to upgrade and getting this error when trying to run application.even my internet is already connected and there is no URL mentioned in my html file.Here is the Scripts:
**INDEX.HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
<title>Survey App</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=no;"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.1.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/jquery.mobile.theme-1.1.1.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/simpledialog.min.css"/>
<link href="css/lib/mobiscroll.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jqm.page.params.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/lib/cordova.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

MoreOver using Windows 7,Eclipse and Android Version 4.2 Api Level 17.
 Snapshot of error![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update  Cordova 2.7.0 jar  and Js  to  Cordova 2.8.0 if you have not updated

Then set

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
```

Comment: i already have updated both of abpve and have added config.xml,cordova directory complete in my project

Comment: yes have set loadUrlTimeOut value and testing this error resolves but my another issue raised i will test two or more times that either my other work is fine or not then will let u know

Comment: can u help me how to increase speed of phonegap aplication its working too slow...... using cordova 2.8.0 and jquery-1.7.1 and jqm 1.3.0

Comment: do you test on emulator

Comment: no on device its buttons sometimes become unrsponsive and they freezed when i scroll the screen then it activates